# How to do logic based on object ID

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

Suppose I have a game, where there are buildings sorted by type. Each type is represented as a separate class, but sometimes I have to do some uncommon logic for the buildings of the same type. How could one implement this kind of behaviour?

For example, I can identify buildings by ID, so I can have a giant switch or command pattern inside the building type class. But I think that something is not right with this approach.

Another approach is to have different class for any divergent logic. But this proposes a lot of small classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is what polymorphism aims to solve, and one of the big differences between procedural and oop programming.  You can achieve it through extending a base class, or by implementing an interface.  Here is extending a base class:

```
public abstract class Building {
    abstract void destroy();
}

public BrickBuilding extends Building {
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        bricks.fallToGround();
    }
}

public HayBuilding extends Building {
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        straw.blowInWind();
    }
}
```

In places in your code where you would have used a switch statement to switch on building type, just hold a reference to the abstract `Building` type, and call method `destroy()` on it:

```
public class BuildingDestroyer {
    public void rampage() {
        for(Building building : allTheBuildings) {
            // Could be a BrickBuilding, or a HayBuilding
            building.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, to address your concern about having a lot of small types, you can 'inject' a `destroy` behaviour you want into a common building type, like so...albeing, you will end up with a lot of different destroy behaviour classes too...so, this might not be a solution.

```
public interface DestroyBehaviour {
    void destroy(Building building);
}

public class Building {
    private int id;
    public DestroyBehaviour destroyBehaviour;

    public Building(int id, DestroyBehaviour destroyBehaviour) {
        this.id = id;
        this.destroyBehaviour = destroyBehaviour;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        destroyBehaviour.destroy(this); // or something along those lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the giant switch by having a BuildingFactory class which exposes a registerBuildingType(typeName, instanceCreatorFunc) method, that each building class calls (from a static initialize method for example) and that gets called with a unique string for that class (class name would suffice) and a static "create" method that returns a new instance.

This approach also has the advantage of being able to load new buildings from dynamically linked libraries.